# Existence of a predicate imposing an order on keywords in Clojure?

Tags: clojure

In racket and scheme, I seem to remember a function called `less` that imposed ordering on all sorts of stuff, not just numbers.

```
(less 'a 'b) ;; -> true
(less 'b 'a) ;; -> false
(less 9 10) ;; -> true
```

Whether this exists in clojure is my main question.

I know that `compare` exists in Clojure, as in `(compare :b :c) ;; -> -1`. However, I want to know if there is simply a predicate for any orderable thing in clojure that returns whether or not the first thing goes before the second thing in the ordering ("less than"), returning a boolean value. For example, how does clojure know that one keyword is "less" than another?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is not such a function, but you can easily create one:

```
(def less (comp neg? compare))
```

`compare` expects the two parameters to implement the `java.util.Comparable` interface or you can pass a `java.util.Comparator` if you don't want to use the objects default compare implementation.

Note that if you try to compare two objects of different classes, you will usually get a ClassCastException. Try `(compare 1 :a)`

In the case of keywords, their compare method just delegates to the implementation of the internal Symbol compare which you can find [here](https://github.com/clojure/clojure/blob/master/src/jvm/clojure/lang/Symbol.java#L104). As you can see, the implementation just delegates to Java's String compare (if you ignore the ns stuff)